# Why would DATEDIFF double the result after first execution?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, datediff, getdate

I am using the following technique to roughly gauge elapsed time to execute a stored procedure via SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio):

```
USE [MyDB]
GO

DECLARE @t1 DATETIME;
DECLARE @t2 DATETIME;
SET @t1 = GETDATE();

DECLARE @TTIdsList dbo.TTIdsList_ident
INSERT INTO @TTIdsList(Id)
VALUES (7890137988314100)
DECLARE @return_value int
EXEC    @return_value = [mySCH].[DataLoadByList]
        @CaseIds = @TTIdsList
SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

SET @t2 = GETDATE();
SELECT DATEDIFF(microsecond,@t1,@t2) AS elapsed_us;
GO
```

It works nicely but it returns a different result on first execution (3000 microseconds). On all subsequent executions it returns double-that: 6000 microseconds.

Am I missing something in the way those variables get initialized? If so, what am I missing?

Comment: It's probably the compilation time for the stored procedure you use. to test this suggestion, move the `SET @t1` to right before the `EXEC...` and the `SET @t2` to right after it and see what happens.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I did exactly as you said and I am still getting the same results: 3000 microseconds first run, 6000 microseconds for 2nd, 3rd, 4th and any subsequent run. BTW, every time I rename `elapsed_us`, it goes back to 3000 microseconds (which I believe is the correct value). Weird.

Comment: So it's the compilation time of the stored procedure. to verify that you can add the `RECOMPILE` hint in the stored procedure. If I'm correct, you will see that the time is now stable on 3000 microseconds.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I don't follow. How would spending time on compilation and execution take less time than just execution?

Comment: @martin correct. I missread the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TSQL `datetime` **does not have microsecond resolution**. The resolution is 1/300th of a second, and this is rounded to three decimal places.

This means that if the actual elapsed time is between 1/300th of a second, and 2/300ths of a second, you will sometimes get 3 milliseconds, and sometimes 6 milliseconds difference.

To get actual values you need a time measurement which has the resolution you seek. Try using the data type `datetime2`, and the function `SYSUTCDATETIME()`, which actually do have enough precision to answer your questions.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb630387.aspx